# Disable Hibernate SQL logging for specific class

Tags: hibernate, log4j

Is there a way to disable the logging of SQL statements for a specific class?

I have enabled SQL statement logging by defining a log4j logger which is fine in general. Unfortunately, I have one class which is called very frequently and produces very lot of output to the console. I would like to disable the logging for only the single class. Is this possible?

Comment: I'm fairly sure that it's not possible.

Comment: Most probably you may not be able to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is possible to define what level each class logs at in log4j 1 for example:

```
<!-- Suppress success logging from InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent -->
<logger name="org.springframework.security">
    <level value="ERROR"/>
</logger>
```

It is not possible to fine tune it.

To get finer control of your logging you will need to upgrade log4j 2.

In Log4j 2 you can use filters:

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/filters.html

here is a snippet of configuration using a regex filter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration status="warn" name="MyApp" packages="">
  <appenders>
    <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="logs/app.log"
                 filePattern="logs/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}.log.gz">
      <RegexFilter regex=".* test .*" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
      <PatternLayout>
        <pattern>%d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n</pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
      <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
    </RollingFile>
  </appenders>
  <loggers>
    <root level="error">
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFile"/>
    </root>
  </loggers>
</configuration>
```

Comment: That;s not what he's asking. Hibernate has a single `org.hibernate.SQL` logger that logs all generated SQL. He want's to prevent hibernate logging queries related to a particular entity from being logged to this logger.

Comment: Must be a bit more specific: I want to introduce Hibernate into a project using Spring JdbcTemplate in the past. I want to disable logging for all statements excuted via JdbcTemplate. SQL statements when a Hibernate object is loaded are OK.

Comment: you could look into log4j 2. have a look at my updated answer.

Comment: If you are happy with this as having solved your problem, then please accept this as the answer by clicking the tick

Answer (score 0):

No, what you ask is not possible.  What if you didn't want logging for a specific class (mapped to a table) but that table is joined to another table.  Do you want the log to show information if the table is part of a join?